# CSS background image size 50%

Tags: css

My website has the following CSS making an image stick to the bottom of the site.

```
#wrapper{
min-height:100%;
background:#fff url(grafikk/bg-footer.gif) no-repeat 50% 100%;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

It words great - the picture is centered and stick to the bottom of the page.

But I'd like to set the picture width to 50% of the original PNG. The PNG is 640px wide, so setting it to 320px is also ok.

How could I do that?

(I was unable to find what the different properties of the background-setting actually mean.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually use pixel values in `background-size`:

```
background-size: 320px 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the property you're looking for is the `background-size`. More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp